# getent returns group with no users

Tags: ldap, solaris, edirectory

I have been struggling to get the expected result from getent.
I've setup a Solaris 9 server to authenticate agains eDirectory Ldap Server. I'm able to authenticate fine.
Only thing is, when I run the id command it returns with no Ldap groups.

I have found that getent group only returns the Group name and GID number but not the members in them.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably looking for memberUid not member, and you do not have memberUid populated.

In eDirectory group membership is denoted with a full DN.  Usually Unix'y LDAP implementations want just the CN= or uid= of the users who are members, thus the memberUid attribute.

Be aware this is defined as case exact string in eDirectory by default as well, so case of the user matters, even though CN and uid are both case ignore string attributes, which is a bit of a strange pain at times.

Comment: http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/printableBug.do?bug_id=6444430